# access the unique pointer across the class without using reference or shared pointer

Tags: c++, singleton, c++17, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Posting Again,
Unique pointer stored in class A, need to access in class B without using shared ptr or reference?. (ie)The owner of that pointer should remain only in class A and the semantic ownership of the pointer should not be shared.
func1, func2, func3 all the places unique pointer is accessed many times.
code snip helps, I am new to smart pointers.

```
class A
{
public:
    static A* Get();
    A();
    virtual ~A();
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> *Getter();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> uniquePointer;
}
```

A.cpp

```
A::A() 
{
   uniquePointer = std::unique_ptr<ABC> new ABC();
}

A::Getter()
{
   return &uniquePointer; => This worked but it is not desirable.
}
```

b.h

```
#include <a.h>
class B {
private:
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
}
```

B.cpp

```
B::func1()
{
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> *getPtrfunc1 = A::Get()->Getter();
}
B::func2()
{
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> *getPtrfunc2 = A::Get()->Getter();
}
B::func3()
{
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> *getPtrfunc3 = A::Get()->Getter();
}
```

Comment: You can get the underlying pointer from a `unique_ptr` via it's `.get()` function. So you can pass along a non owning pointer. Also it's recommended to use `std::make_unique` for creating the `unique_ptr`. But the question isn't crystal clear on what you want to achieve

Comment: Yes, Thank you. This will work , similar to @Remy Lebeau suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the semantic ownership of the pointer should not be shared

Don't don't pass around access to the `unique_ptr` at all.  Pass around a raw pointer to the `ABC` that the `unique_ptr` owns, eg:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    static A* Get();
    A();
    ABC* Getter();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> uniquePointer;
};
```

```
A::A() 
{
   uniquePointer = std::make_unique<ABC>();
}

A* A::Get()
{
    static A a;
    return &a;
}

ABC* A::Getter()
{
   return uniquePointer.get();
}
```

```
#include <a.h>

class B {
private:
    void func1();
    void func2();
    void func3();
}
```

```cpp
void B::func1()
{
    ABC *getPtrfunc1 = A::Get()->Getter();
}

void B::func2()
{
    ABC *getPtrfunc2 = A::Get()->Getter();
}

void B::func3()
{
    ABC *getPtrfunc3 = A::Get()->Getter();
}
```